# Removing rows with a rule from another column

Tags: r

I have data similar to this:

```
PatientID=c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3)
VisitId=c(1,5,6,9,2,3,12,4,7,8,10,11) 
target=c(0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0)

as.data.frame(cbind(PatientID,VisitId,target))

   PatientID VisitId target
1          1       1      0
2          1       5      0
3          1       6      0
4          1       9      1
5          2       2      0
6          2       3      0
7          2      12      0
8          3       4      0
9          3       7      0
10         3       8      0
11         3      10      1
12         3      11      0
```

I would need to delete rows, that have a VisitId per PatientID equal or larger than the VisitId of a row where the target is 1.

Ie in the example case rows 4, 11 and 12 should be eliminated, because those are rows that occurred for this patient at the same time or after the target incident happened - which I wish to predict...

Comment: why a -1 for the question? what's wrong with it?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an idea using `dplyr`. This makes the assumption that you only have 1 or none `1` as target in each `patientid`

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
 group_by(PatientID) %>% 
 mutate(new = ifelse(target == 1, VisitId, 0), 
        new = replace(new, new == 0, max(new))) %>% 
 filter(target != 1 & VisitId < new | new == 0) %>% 
 select(-new)
```

which gives,

> ```
> # A tibble: 9 x 3
> # Groups:   PatientID [3]
>   PatientID VisitId target
>       <dbl>   <dbl>  <dbl>
> 1         1       1      0
> 2         1       5      0
> 3         1       6      0
> 4         2       2      0
> 5         2       3      0
> 6         2      12      0
> 7         3       4      0
> 8         3       7      0
> 9         3       8      0
> ```